# Automatic bounds checking?

Tags: c, arrays, string, overflow, buffer

I'm pretty new to programming, and have been studying C.  I am trying to generate a simple buffer overflow and be able to predict the results as an excercise, but in trying to do so, was unable to even create the overflow.  I am using MinGW, and it seems to automatically adjust my array to fit the contents.  I am compiling with -Wall and -Wextra, but no errors are kicked out.  What exactly is happening here?  Why don't I get a segfault?  Shouldn't my nNum get written-over?  And shouldn't something complain when I make a random write to somewhere I shouldn't touch?  Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*  Array index - something to be sure that you're outside of szArray  */
#define SZ_LOCATION 15

int main(void)
{
    /*  Initialize array and number.  Store 1000 to number, and "hello\0" to array  */
    char szArray[6];
    unsigned short nNum = 1000;
    strcpy(szArray, "hello");

    printf("SZ_LOCATION = %i\n\n", SZ_LOCATION);

    /*  Print current contents of szArray ("hello").  Print the char at the preset index location, and the current (unchanged) value of nNum  */
    printf("szArray = %s\n", szArray);
    printf("szArray[SZ_LOCATION] = %c\n", szArray[SZ_LOCATION]);
    printf("nNum = %d\n\n", nNum);

    /*  Add 3 chars to szArray, to push it over 6 chars.  Re-print all variables  */
    strcat(szArray, "BIG");
    printf("szArray = %s\t(%I64u bytes)\nszArray[7] = %c\nnNum = %d\n\n", szArray, sizeof(szArray), szArray[sizeof(szArray) + 1], nNum);

    /*  Store a random char to the preset location in the array, way out there, and re-print its contents, with the new size of the array  */
    szArray[SZ_LOCATION] = 'h';
    printf("szArray = %s\nszArray[SZ_LOCATION] = %c\nsizeof(szArray) = %I64u\n", szArray, szArray[SZ_LOCATION], sizeof(szArray));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program is working fine(I mean it is giving me strack smashing error), What do you wan't achieve? I compiled with `gcc -Wall`

Comment: Because undefined behavior does not mean you'll always *see* it; it means that someday, somewhere, when you're giving a demo to a potential buying partner that writes eight-figure checks, you'll likely see it *then* (and so shall they, and then there will be much crying, wailing, and gnashing of teeth...). You're asking for "definitive" action from something that is "undefined".

Comment: @WhozCraig There should be a really big banner at the entry of [C] tag. This question is repeated every single day in never-ending variety of forms :)

Comment: @WhozCraig     I see what you are saying.  Perhaps I was just expecting C to hold my hand more than it is going to.  After reading alk's response, I think I can see what is going on.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3316425 Apart form compile-time checks (and they're pretty basic) C holds your had literally as much as assembly language does. I.e. it doesn't. A long-ago common phrase was "C : All the power of assembly language with the safety of... assembly language."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
/*  Add 3 chars to szArray, to push it over 6 chars.  Re-print all variables  */
strcat(szArray, "BIG");
printf("szArray = %s\t(%I64u bytes)\nszArray[7] = %c\nnNum = %d\n\n", szArray, sizeof(szArray), szArray[sizeof(szArray) + 1], nNum);
```

to be

```
while (1)
{
  /*  Add 3 chars to szArray, to push it over 6 chars.  Re-print all variables  */
  strcat(szArray, "BIG");
  printf("szArray = %s\t(%I64u bytes)\nszArray[7] = %c\nnNum = %d\n\n", szArray, sizeof(szArray), szArray[sizeof(szArray) + 1], nNum);
}
```

and monitor the program's output.

Comment: I got my segfault with this.  It also worked when I started incrementing szArray, and changing its contents.  I think I can see more of what is happening with this now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't adjust your array to fit the contents. By dramatical coincidence, addressing beyond the limit of array didn't break anything important. More specific: array was allocated on stack, and you write far enough to not mess with temporary `push`/`pop`s, or the compiler decided that they were not needed at all, and you touch unused stack space. Please touch something *just after* or *just before* to get any effect.